# Regex to start with one of three options

Tags: javascript, regex

I am building a simple form using `HTML`. I am using `Javascript` to perform client side validation on the various input fields. One such field is the Phone number field. I am trying to write a `Regular Expression` that will accept the following:

- Must start with one of the following three options

  - +44
  - 0044
  - 44
- Must then accept the following

  - Digits from 0 - 9
  - Spaces
  - Hyphens
  - Full stops

Currently, I've the following expression: `/^\+([0-9])([ .-]*\d){7,20}$/`. However this will only accept numbers beginning with +44 rather then numbers beginning with +44 OR 0044 OR 44. My question is how can I modify the above Regular expression in order to check to ensure the number begins with one of the three options?

Many thanks in advance for your help.

**Note**

*A sincere thanks to @melpomene for teaching me the ways of SO and how to struture my questions in an adequate and logical format. I don't know where I'd be today if it weren't for you! :)*

Comment: Which regex dialect is this?

Comment: Decide what you want: Is it "ONLY numbers" or "accepting hypens, spaces and dots"?

Comment: I want to accept Hypens, spaces and dots along with numbers but the input MUST start with +44 or 0044 or 44

Comment: Are you doing this inside a programming language? (Java, Ruby, Python) It would be helpful to know the context, as @melpomene pointed out that there are different dialects of regex

Comment: Yes, I am doing it within JQuery for Client Side validation.

Comment: @Javacadabra The language is called "javascript".

Comment: Jesus christ guys.....gimmie a break I asked a simple question ffs

Comment: @Javacadabra No, you didn't (I see no question). You asked us to write code for you, without specifying the language the code should be in.

Comment: Yes....and then I mentioned I was using JQuery to do it. One would then assume I was using Javascript wouldn't they?

Comment: No one reads comments. Put all relevant information in the main post. You still haven't fixed the "ONLY numbers" thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`^(?:\+|00)?44[\d\s\-.]*\d$` will match +44, 0044 and 44 followed by any number of either digits, spaces, hyphens or dots. The final `\d` ensures that the match finishes with a number.

Comment: There was a mistake in there, I forgot the final '$', which I've now corrected.  Otherwise it fits your requirements. This actually requires the string to match to be trimmed, i.e. having all leading and trailing spaces removed.

Comment: I'd be happy to accept the answer, however someone posted the following regex here: ^(\+4{2}|0{2}4{2}|4{2})[\d -.]* which works perfectly for me. They even provided an explanation line for line but for some reason deleted their answer! I used that Regex.

Comment: I've seen that too, but I have 2 objections to that one: it accepts phone numbers ending in symbols (which usually means the user has made an input error) and using the 4{2} pattern is overly complicated / unreadable since a simple 44 will suffice.

Comment: Edited; sorry, accidentally pressed enter and submitted before I was done.

Comment: Hey thanks, that's a really good explanation. Thank you. Your solution is definitely better.

Answer (score 5):

If you put

```
(\+|00)?
```

before your regex, it accepts (optional) a `+` or `00` before it.

Try with

```
^(\+|00)?([0-9])([ .-]*\d){7,12}$
```

Regards